Movie about a woman who comes to life again
Trying to find a movie but can't remember the actors or characters, just a few moments from the plot. I saw it 6 or 7 years ago so it was released in 2010 or earlier. I suppose it's a scifi one.
Scientists? find a womans body which is frozen in ice, or just they find a DNA, something similar. The main thing is that a woman comes to life again. I don't know if she is from another planet or she lived earlier but I'm sure she doesn't speak the other characters' language. I can't remember what happens after that, just a scene when one of the male characters explains her the meaning of "I'm sorry."
Later we find out that this woman is suffering from a disease which is dangerous to other people and because of that the scientists want to destroy her. There's a scene when she says "I'm sorry" when she talks to the male character that I mentioned.
I know it's a bit chaotic. Unfortunatelly I haven't seen the whole movie but I'd like to watch it. Any possible movies that fit the description? It's also possible that it's an episode of something.
